# Compiling an old version of gcc on a modern system

Tags: c, gcc

I was messing around with ancient versions of the Linux kernel, and I wanted to build the first release, 0.01. And that quickly went nowhere, it would require modification of the source, and I didn't want to do that.
I tried to set up an old build environment with GCC 3.0, I configured it for "i486-linux", adding -m32 to CFLAGS, and setting std to gnu90. It would almost compile until it gets to this error here:

```
cp/decl.c:13472:25: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
13472 |   current_binding_level = bl;
```

And if you look at the offending code:

```c
  /* Initialize RTL machinery.  We cannot do this until
     CURRENT_FUNCTION_DECL and DECL_RESULT are set up.  We do this
     even when processing a template; this is how we get
     CFUN set up, and our per-function variables initialized.
     FIXME factor out the non-RTL stuff.  */
  bl = current_binding_level;
  init_function_start (decl1, input_filename, lineno);
  current_binding_level = bl;
```

It's trying to set `current_binding_level`, a macro defined as:

```c
/* The binding level currently in effect.  */

#define current_binding_level           \
  (cfun && cp_function_chain->bindings      \
   ? cp_function_chain->bindings        \
   : scope_chain->bindings)
```

to the value of `bl`.
Can I build this on a modern system, or is it useless to try?

Comment: I don't know if it's relevant, but [C99 p6.5.15](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/n1256.html#6.5.15) footnote 95: "A conditional expression does not yield an lvalue." C89 has the same restriction [in footnote 41](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c89/c89-draft.html#3.3.15). You're using `gnu89` though... so take this with a grain of salt.

Comment: You should be able to convert `(c ? x : y) = v;`, which is illegal C, to `*(c ? &x : &y) = v;`  This will have the equivalent effect, provided `x` and `y` have the same type.  In your example, this could all be done in the macro.

Comment: By the way, I think pre-ANSI gcc used to allow this construct, but ANSI rejected this extension, and I believe gcc eventually stopped allowing it as well.  I don't know if there's a gcc option to re-enable it.

Comment: You might have to first compile a not-as-old gcc version and use that to bootstrap the 3.0 version.

Comment: What is the reason to use an old system (apart from easier leaning of the implementation) ?